# It it safe to remove GA kernels when using HWE?

Tags: apt, upgrade, kernel, 22.04, hardware-enablement-stack

I am running Ubuntu 22.04 with ZFS on root. My boot partition is only 1.8GB - I find that it is constantly running out of space with snapshots of just a couple kernel updates.

`dpkg -l | grep linux-image | grep ^ii` reports that I have 4 kernels installed:

```
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-100-generic             5.15.0-100.110                          amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-92-generic              5.15.0-92.102                           amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-6.5.0-17-generic               6.5.0-17.17~22.04.1                     amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-6.5.0-25-generic               6.5.0-25.25~22.04.1                     amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic                        5.15.0.100.97                           amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04              6.5.0.25.25~22.04.12                    amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

Ideally, I would only have 2 kernels installed at a time to keep snapshots smaller.  However, `sudo apt autoremove` insists on keeping 2 HWE (6.5.*) and 2 GA (5.15.*) kernels around.

I only am using the HWE kernels and not the GA ones.  `sudo apt remove linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic --dry-run` suggests that this would allow the GA kernels to be auto removed.  My question is whether it is safe to do this?  Will it potentially cause problems in the future when upgrading to a new version of Ubuntu?

I also noticed that the `linux-generic` package isn't installed, only `linux-generic-hwe-20.04` (not sure why) and `linux-generic-hwe-22.04`.  So I'm wondering if maybe the `linux-image-generic` and `linux-headers-generic` shouldn't be there either?

Comment: Yes, you may remove the meta packages, `linux-image-generic` and `linux-headers-generic`. You may have the meta package HWE 20.04 if you upgraded from that version.